# Heroku PHP project, foreman start error locally - "program requires PHP 5.5.11 or newer" error code 1

Tags: php, heroku, composer-php, foreman

I get the following error when attempting to launch the app locally:

```
nick$ foreman start
23:56:24 web.1  | started with pid 98467
23:56:24 web.1  | This program requires PHP 5.5.11 or newer; check your 'php-fpm' command.
23:56:24 web.1  | exited with code 1
23:56:24 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes
```

I have PHP **5.5.15** running locally:

```
nick$ php -v PHP 5.5.15 (cli) (built: Aug 15 2014 15:09:30)  Copyright
(c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c)
1998-2014 Zend Technologies
```

Procfile contents:

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2
```

php-fpm output:

```
nick$ php-fpm
[16-Aug-2014 00:06:32] ERROR: failed to open configuration file '/private/etc/php-fpm.conf': No such file or directory (2)
[16-Aug-2014 00:06:32] ERROR: failed to load configuration file '/private/etc/php-fpm.conf'
[16-Aug-2014 00:06:32] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
```

Any idea what might be happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your `php-fpm` command isn't 5.5.15 (looks like you built that yourself). It usually gets installed to `/usr/local/sbin` or similar (`.../sbin` in any case), and I guess unlike `.../bin`, that one isn't on your `$PATH`.

Check `php-fpm -v` to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

Uninstalled older php-fpm version. 
Uninstalled homebrew php5.5.
Reinstalled php5.5 with fpm